# where does the yield store value in python

Tags: python, generator, yield

I understand `generator` generates value once at a time, which could save a lot memory and not like `list` which stores all value in memory.

I want to know in `python`, how `yield` knows which value should be returned during the iteration without storing all data at once in memory?

In my understanding, if i want to print `1 to 100` using `yield`, it is necessary that `yield` needs to know or store `1 to 100` first and then move point one by one to return value ?

If not, then how `yield` return value once at a time, but without storing all value in memory?

Comment: It pauses the function at every `yield` until the value is consumed by something. You can observe it by sprinkling some `print` statements in your generator.

Comment: [Reading material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It's that related to some kind of data structure?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#Comparison_with_generators

Comment: While the implementation of generators is not guaranteed, coroutines would be a relatively easy way to go about it and would certainly work for didactic purposes.

Comment: Do you remember every word you have ever spoken?  You don't really need to, in order to speak your next sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, `yield` delays the execution but remembers where it left off. However, more specifically, when `yield` is called, the variables in the state of the generator function are saved in a "frozen" state. When `yield` is called again, the built in `next` function sends back the data in line to be transmitted. If there is no more data to be yielded (hence a `StopIteration` is raised), the generator data stored in its "frozen" state is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Each time a generator `yield`s, the stack frame of the generator is saved off inside the generator object, so [it can be restored when execution resumes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/genobject.c#L184) (when the next value is requested).

You can see [the structure definition on CPython here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Include/genobject.h#L15).

If you want to see more, generators are somewhat introspectable, so you can take a look at, say, the progression of the locals, the line number it's currently on, etc.:

```
def myrange(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i

mr = myrange(10)

# Before any values consumed:
print(mr.gi_frame.f_locals)  # Outputs {'n': 10}
print(mr.gi_frame.f_lineno)  # Outputs 1

next(mr)  # Advance one

print(mr.gi_frame.f_locals)  # Outputs {'n': 10, 'i': 0}
print(mr.gi_frame.f_lineno)  # Outputs 3

list(mr)  # Consumes generator

print(mr.gi_frame)  # Outputs None; the frame is discarded when the generator finishes
```